# How to include plus symbol to a numeric keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

I was wondering how to implement in my application a TextFormField with a numeric keyboard that includes the plus("+") with the intention of including of facilitating the user to input international phone numbers.

```
 TextFormField(
    controller: phoneNumberController,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number, // Fix to include plus symbol
),
```

Comment: if this answer was  useful please checked like accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change type  TextInputType.number at  TextInputType.phone

```
TextFormField(
    controller: phoneNumberController,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone, // Fix to include plus symbol
),
```

Comment: Wow Thank you very much Elvis, I allways get stuck when theyres such a simple solution!